# How to solve "Perf Ring Buffer Error" from Sysmon?

Tags: linux, logging, buffer, splunk

I'm trying to forward data from my notebook to a Splunk instance using Universal Forwarder and Sysmon for Linux.

When I boot the notebook everything works perfectly and Splunk receives data from the syslog file in /var/log directory that Sysmon populates with logs from the system. But after 2 hours Sysmon starts giving the same log messages:

```
ago 24 13:13:23 host sysmon[1238]: Perf Ring Buffer Error: -95 @ 2023-08-24T15:14:11Z
```

Is there a way to clear the perf ring buffer or just increase the rate of data that is drained from it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.